# Getting all data from table based on date by using php web services

Tags: php, soap

I wrote a php web service to get all data when `coins` were greater than 0. Here is the code:
**`organisationListClient-Copy.php`**

```
<?php
require_once("lib/nusoap.php");
// Create the client instance
$client = new nusoap_client("http://localhost/TTrockstars/ws/organisationListWS-copy.php");
//check if there were any instantiation errors, and if so stop execution with an error message:
$error = $client->getError();
echo ($error);
if ($error) {
    die("client construction error: {$error}\n");
}

// Call the SOAP method
$result = $client->call("getOrganisationList");

$error = $client->getError();

if ($error) {
    print_r($client->response);
    print_r($client->getDebug());
    die();
}

// Display the result
// echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
//$fichero = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/'.$imgname, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
//echo ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/data/');
// echo "</pre>";



?>
```

**`organisationListWS-Copy.php`**

```
<?php
    //****including config file****
include 'config.php';

function getOrganisationList() {

    $db = dataBaseConn();
    $con = mysqli_connect($db['DB_SERVER'],$db['DB_USER'],$db['DB_PASSWORD'],$db['DB_DATABASE']);

    if($con){
        mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
        /*$orgListRS = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT name  FROM prop ");*/
        $orgListRS = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, name, image, extra_image  FROM prop where coins > 0");
        $orgList = [];

        while($orgListRow = mysqli_fetch_array($orgListRS, MYSQLI_BOTH)){

                //id
            $usrId = $orgListRow['id'];
            $usrId = str_replace(",", ",", $usrId);
            $usrId = str_replace(" ", " ", $usrId);
            $orgList[] = $usrId;

                //name      
            $usrName = $orgListRow['name'];
            $usrName = str_replace("’", "'", $usrName);
            $usrName = str_replace(" ", " ", $usrName);
            $orgList[] = $usrName;

                //image
            $usrImage = $orgListRow['image'];
            $usrImage = str_replace("", "", $usrImage);
            $usrImage = str_replace(" ", " ", $usrImage);
            $orgList[] = $usrImage;

                //extra image
            $usrExtimage = $orgListRow['extra_image'];
            $usrExtimage = str_replace(",", ",", $usrExtimage);
            $usrExtimage = str_replace(" ", " ", $usrExtimage);
            $orgList[] = $usrExtimage;


        }
        mysqli_free_result($orgListRS);
        $replyJson["status"]="SUCCESS";
        $replyJson["orgList"]= $orgList;
        mysqli_close($con);
        return json_encode($replyJson);

    }else{
        $replyJson["status"]="FAILED";
        return json_encode($replyJson);
    }

}

require_once("lib/nusoap.php");

$urlPrefix = nameSpaceURL();

$URL       = $urlPrefix . "/ws/organisationListWS-copy.php";
$namespace = $URL . '?wsdl';

$server = new soap_server();

$server->configureWSDL("WebServices for getting list of organisations");

$server->register("getOrganisationList",    
    array(),
                // return value(s):
    array('return'=>'xsd:string'),
                // namespace:
    $namespace,
                // soapaction: (use default)
    false,
                // style: rpc or document
    'rpc',
                // use: encoded or literal
    'encoded',
                // description: documentation for the method
    'Return list of organistaions');

$_HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : "";
$server->service($_HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);

?>
```

When I run it in browser, I get all ids, names, images and extra images whose coins are greater than 0. Here is a screen shot:
[image: img]
Here is my table structure:
[image: img1]
now I need to change the `sql` query like this:

```
if (updated_date=="new_date") { 
//Send all data (return ids, names, images, extra images whose coins are greater than 0)
}
else { 
//Get ids, names, images and extra images which are added after updated date
}
```

How can I modify current `sql` query to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Thats fairly simple, you just need to create the new criteria for your query if the condition exists, and add it to the original query. If the condiftion does not exist `$extraCriteria` will be empty and no chnage will be made to the original query.

```
$extraCriteria = '';
if ($updated_date !== "new_date") { 
    //Get ids, names, images and extra images which are added after updated date
    $extraCriteria = " AND updated_date > '$updated_date'";
}  


$orgListRS = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, name, image, extra_image  
                                 FROM prop 
                                 where coins > 0 
                                 $extraCriteria");
```

I am of course guessing the actual names of your columns and variables but I hope this gives you a basic idea.

Comment: Yeah, got the logic. But do you see `updated_at` parameter in table? It contains updated dates